# Кнопка в CSS (bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap

в чем разница? 
ведь класс должен быть один, а тут два варианта у меня получается

```
<form action="" method="get" class="form">
```

так работает

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
```

и так тоже работает, но выглядит по другому

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-success">
```

Comment: В чём у вас конкретно вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.btn -- основной класс кнопки

.btn-success -- расширеяет вид основной кнопки.

.btn -- обязательный класс,

.btn-success использовать без .btn --считаю не корректным.

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

в классе .btn пишется основа

```
.btn{
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 1.42857143;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        vertical-align: middle;
        -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
        touch-action: manipulation;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        background-image: none;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Если этих правил не хватает используем "уточненние", еще один класс который дополняет новыми правилами и перезаписывает те которые накладывают нежелательные свойства.

```
.btn-success{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
    border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```

Как мы видим, класс .btn-success всего лишь изменит цвет рамки, текста и цвет фона. Класс можно применить хоть к тегу `<p>` -- но похожим на кнопку тег, от этого не станет.

В вашем примере использована методология(или стиль) [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons).

..кстати класс может быть и чаще всего не один у одного элемента, а вот id и name должен быть одним.
к примеру со страницы главной яндекса:

```
<div class="b-inline b-head-tabs__tab b-head-tabs__tab_selected b-head-tabs-list__item_pos_first">Поиск</div>
```

--обратите внимание на название классов. --такой стиль, вернее сказать, методология имеет название BEM [Блок-Элемент-Модификатор](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=bem)